# Problem Edit data devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

hello a greeting when I try to edit a record in ajax comes

```
 {"suggestions": [{"value": "Pendiente","data": 1},{"value": "Programar","data": 2},}
```

but when I edit the record it brings me the number I mean DATA but it shows me the number and I want to obtain it is the value. any ideas?

my code:

```
$('#eestado').val(estatus); // example estatus = 1
$('#eestado').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '{{ url('/getestados/') }}',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        $('#eestado').val(suggestion.data);
    },
    formatResult: function(suggestion, currentValue){
        if (suggestion.data === null) {
            return "Create a new tag";
        }

        return suggestion.value;
    },
    onInvalidateSelection: function() {
        $('#eestado').val('');
    }
});
```

I use pluggins it's use [Jquery/autocomplete](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your jQuery UI code does not appear to match the jQuery UI options and methods for AutoComplete ( http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ ). Are you using some additional plugin?

Comment: it's use [Jquery/autocomplete](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

Comment: Ok, I do not see `serviceUrl` as an Option for Autocomplete. I do not see `onSelect`, `formatResult`, or `onInvalidateSelection` as events for Autocomplete. This is why I asked, they are not valid for that widget.

Comment: Also, where does the request term get passed to your URL so that it knows what specific elements to display in the result set?

Comment: It is that if you see the url of the plugin that I am using you will see that it is not the same plugin that you comment.

Comment: Ok, I see, so it's https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/ and NOT jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intersted using jQuery UI AutoComplete, then you will want to review the following example:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

With your code, it would look something like this, with **jQuery UI AutoComplete**

```js
var estatus = 1;
var exampleData = {
  "suggestions": [{
    "value": "Pendiente",
    "data": 1
  }, {
    "value": "Programar",
    "data": 2
  }]
};
$(function() {
  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $('#eestado').val(estatus); // example estatus = 1
  $('#eestado').on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
      $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var url = "{{ url('/getestados/') }}";
      var results = [];
      $.get(url, {
        q: extractLast(req.term)
      }, function(data) {
        $.each(data.suggestions, function(k, v) {
          results.push({
            label: v.value,
            value: v.data
          });
        });
      });
      resp(results);
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var terms = split(this.value);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="eestado" type="text" />
```

**For jQuery Autocomplete**

In your comment you mention you are using an alternate jQuery AutoComplete method: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

They say:

> **Known Issues**
>
> If you use it with jQuery UI library it also has plugin named autocomplete. In this case you can use plugin alias devbridgeAutocomplete:
>
> `$('.autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete({ ... });`

So be mindful if you include both libraries. For your code, I would only change one element:

```
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
  $('#eestado').val(suggestion.value);
}
```

When a user makes a selection, the `value` will appear in the input and not the `data`.

Full Code:

```
$('#eestado').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: '{{ url('/getestados/') }}',
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    $('#eestado').val(suggestion.value);
  },
  formatResult: function(suggestion, currentValue){
    if (suggestion.data === null) {
      return "Create a new tag";
    }
    return suggestion.value;
  },
  onInvalidateSelection: function() {
    $('#eestado').val('');
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very well I will try to verify that procedure, thank you very much ... I will adjust and see the result. +1

Comment: But I want the text to be shown and the value is the number

Comment: @GustavoHerrera See the second half of the answer regarding your specific code.

Comment: try as you mention in the second part as you mention, but when loading the form the field shows me is the id and not the text. Now when I delete the information and write another, I get the letter, but when I see its value it is letter and not number. That is the problem that I presently present. But it happens when editing

Comment: @GustavoHerrera based o nyour description, your form is loading with `$('#eestado').val(estatus); ` and you mentioned that `estatus` is `1`. So I am not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: If exact when loading the form to edit brings me the value 1 but its relation is with suggetions.value = "pending" if for example I edit another record where status = 2 then the suggetions.value = "Schedule"...

Comment: I'm doing it in another way to make it work, but I do not think it's the right one, it's that I put hidden input and I pass the value and the visible input shows the data. But I do not think it's the right way.

Comment: @GustavoHerrera I would advise you to edit your post and include more details. It sounds like there is something more going on and comments are not clear.